# MySQL: Select categories and all realated subcategories in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hy, I have 2 tables, `categories(id, name, slug)` and `subcategories(id, name, slug, category)`.

I need to get all the categories + the subcategories but as an array 'field'. My query right now is

```
SELECT c.id AS catId, c.name AS catName, c.slug AS catSlug, s.id AS subcatId, s.name AS subcatName, s.slug AS subcatSlug
FROM categories AS c
LEFT JOIN subcategories AS s ON c.id = s.category
```

The result is this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [catId] => 5
            [catName] => calzature
            [catSlug] => calzature
            [subcatId] => 10
            [subcatName] => eleganti
            [subcatSlug] => eleganti
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [catId] => 5
            [catName] => calzature
            [catSlug] => calzature
            [subcatId] => 11
            [subcatName] => sportive
            [subcatSlug] => sportive
        )

    ....

)
```

I want to group them as follows

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [catId] => 5
                [catName] => calzature
                [catSlug] => calzature
                [subcategories] => array(
                    [0] => array(
                        [subcatId] => 1,
                        [subcatName] => Subcategory name,
                        [subcatSlug] => subcategory-slug,
                    ),
                    [1] => array(
                        [subcatId] => 2,
                        [subcatName] => Another Subcategory name,
                        [subcatSlug] => another-subcategory-slug,
                    ),
                    .....
                )
            )
```

My objective is to create a dropdown menu where the main `<li>` is the category name and the secondary `<li>` are the subcategories.

How can I accomplish this in one query if possible ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid post processing the returned data from you sql query?

Comment: You already have one query which is going to return one table with all the information you need. If you want to structure that information further, you'll need to do that in Ruby. SQL doesn't return Ruby data structures.

Comment: @the_pete Basically yes, I could just process the data and format it as I need it, but I was wondering if I could do it in one query.   The loop to create the menu is like this `foreach ( $categories as $category ) { //output category name and perform another loop like foreach ( $categories->subcategories as $subcategory ) { // output subcategories list } }`

Comment: @C.Ovidiu mysql just returns data in rows and columns... to do that in mysql you would need to do two selects.